# Make this Equation look better aligned (Mathtools vs Plain Style)

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, cases

I have tried to search but I haven't found an answer that works here.

[image: Displayed Equation].

The code for the first block of the code is shown below

```
\[X\left(n\right)\mathrm{=\ }\left\{\mathrm{\ } \begin{array}{c}
\left[\frac{y}{\mathrm{1-}y\mathrm{*}\mathrm{(}r\mathrm{\ }mod\mathrm{\
}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{y}\mathrm{)}}\right]\left[\left(\alpha
\mathrm{*}\left(\frac{F_{current}}{F_{init}}\right)\right)\mathrm{+\
}\left(\left(\mathrm{1-}\alpha \right)\mathrm{*}d_{g}\right)\right]\mathrm{\
}if\mathrm{\ }n\mathrm{\ }\epsilon \mathrm{\ }G\mathrm{,\ }n\mathrm{\
}same\mathrm{\ }quadrant\mathrm{\ }as\mathrm{\ }g \\ 
\left[\frac{y}{\mathrm{1-}y\mathrm{*}\mathrm{(}r\mathrm{\ }mod\mathrm{\
}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{y}\mathrm{)}}\right]\left[\left(\mathrm{(1-}\alpha
\mathrm{)*}\left(\frac{F_{current}}{F_{init}}\right)\right)\mathrm{+\
}\left(\left(\alpha \right)\mathrm{*}d_{g}\right)\right]\mathrm{\
}if\mathrm{\ }n\mathrm{\ }\epsilon \mathrm{\ }G\mathrm{,\ }n\mathrm{\
}is\mathrm{\ }opposite\mathrm{\ }to\mathrm{\ \ }g \\
```

[image]

Comment: How did you managed to get this horrible code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jagath! I used a software to convert from word to latex. I would appreciate a simpler and better approach.

Comment: code is not compilable. In it is missing at least end of math environment ...

Comment: Yes Zarko! I guess the space was not enough. The code ends with     end{array} ]. I just put a part of the code.

Comment: @Abdulhameed Always try to include compilable code (MWE). This makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Abdulhameed, Can you please edit the question title to be more descriptive and comprehensive since the answers are informative and don't deserve to be lost by your misleading title?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Diaa, I hope you may suggest a suitable title. Then I could edit it and acknowledge that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, this should serve as starting point how to rewrite your code manually. Conversion from Word is really awful and not usable ...

[image]

I repeat the firs equation row three times and left second and third row to rewrite and given example of the first line to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
X(n) = 
\begin{dcases}
\left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\alpha\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + (1-\alpha)d_{g}\right]
    &   \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ same \dots}    \\
\left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[(1-\alpha)\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + \alpha d_{g}\right]
    &   \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ i\dots}    \\
\left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + \frac{\alpha}{2} d_{g}\right]
    &   \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ is opposite to } g 
        \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Beside LaTeX problem in your code snippet are also some math problems:

- what means `*`? Is this convolution or multiplication?
- subscript texts: what is names and what is indices?
- etc.

Instead of array I use `dcases` environment from `mathtools`. You can also use `array` as it is in your code sniped, but than change column types from `c` to `l` to achieve desired align.

**Edit:** I consider @egreg suggestion ans accordingly replace `\mathit` with `\text` and `\mod` with `\bmod`. Also I try to wrote second and third cases rows as I see on provided image.

Below is version with use of `array`, which gives similar result as with `dcases`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
X(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
    \left[\alpha\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + (1-\alpha)d_{g}\right]
        &   \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ same \dots}    \\[3ex]
    \left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
    \left[(1-\alpha)\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + \alpha d_{g}\right]
        &   \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ i\dots}        \\[3ex]
    \left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
    \left[\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + \frac{\alpha}{2} d_{g}\right]
        &   \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ is opposite to } g 
        \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

The use of  * as multiplication symbol is more or less limited to use in programming languages. In math, I discourage its use.

[image]

**Edit (2):**
Persisting to not use `mathtools` package with all advantages as new math environments etc, which it provide, is not very reasonable. In this particular case instead of it you can use `amsmath` (`mathtools` is actually enhanced version of `amsmath`) if this somehow helps.

In the second solution, given in the first edit, from both packages is used only macro `\text{...}`, which enable writing text as outside of the math environment. You can emulate it (with many limitation as is only one-line text) with `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
X(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
    \left[\alpha\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + (1-\alpha)d_{g}\right]
        &   \mbox{if } n \in G, n \mbox{ same \dots}    \\[3ex]
    \left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
    \left[(1-\alpha)\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + \alpha d_{g}\right]
        &   \mbox{if } n \in G, n \mbox{ i\dots}        \\[3ex]
    \left[\frac{y}{1- y\left(r \bmod \frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
    \left[\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{F_{\mathrm{current}}}{F_{\mathrm{init}}} + \frac{\alpha}{2} d_{g}\right]
        &   \mbox{if } n \in G, n \mbox{ is opposite to } g
        \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

If also this (degradation of elegant solution, based on very standard approach of math typesetting) is not satisfactory solution, you still can use your original code.

Comment: Thanks! Zarko! I couldnt get the mathtools package. * means multiplication. I only changed the variables

Comment: The `*` are used as multiplication more or less only in programming languages, not in math, I discourage to use it. I don't know, which latex distribution you use. In MikTeX the servers seems to be temporary down. You can obtain it from CTAN, but after manualy installation in some local TeX tree you need to refresh database.

Comment: Thanks! Zarko! Your output looks fine. I couldnt get the mathtools package. * means multiplication. I only changed the variables

Comment: It should be `\bmod`, not `\mod`. And `\text`, not `\mathit`

Comment: @egreg, thank you for comment. I consider them in edit of my answer.

Comment: @Abdulhameed, MikTeX servers and its mirrors are back, so you can (if you use it) now simply install missing packages with package manager.

Comment: @Abdulhameed, see second edit. It offer solution without use of `mathtools` However, I strongly encourage to use `mathtools`. If you have problem to upgrade your LaTeX distribution with this very valuable package, ask new question, where show, what is your problem.

Comment: You've done well Zarko! Thanks. I guess I may need to create another question regarding  my mathtools upgrade issues.

Answer (score 5):

I dont know whether this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\def\mult{\times}

\begin{equation}
X(n) = 
\begin{cases}
\left[\frac{y}{1-y\mult\left(r\bmod\frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\left(\alpha\mult\left(\frac{F_{\mathit{current}}}{F_{\mathit{init}}}\right)\right)
+ ((1-\alpha)\mult d_g)\right] & \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ sam}\ldots\\[15pt]
\left[\frac{y}{1-y\mult\left(r\bmod\frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\left((1-\alpha)\mult\left(\frac{F_{\mathit{current}}}{F_{\mathit{init}}}\right)\right)
+ ((\alpha)\mult d_g)\right] & \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ i}\ldots\\[15pt]
\left[\frac{y}{1-y\mult\left(r\bmod\frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\mult\left(\frac{F_{\mathit{current}}}{F_{\mathit{init}}}\right)\right)
+ \left(\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\mult d_g\right)\right] & \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ is diffe}\ldots\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\def\mult{*}

\begin{equation}
X(n) = 
\begin{cases}
\left[\frac{y}{1-y\mult\left(r\bmod\frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\left(\alpha\mult\left(\frac{F_{\mathit{current}}}{F_{\mathit{init}}}\right)\right)
+ ((1-\alpha)\mult d_g)\right] & \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ sam}\ldots\\[15pt]
\left[\frac{y}{1-y\mult\left(r\bmod\frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\left((1-\alpha)\mult\left(\frac{F_{\mathit{current}}}{F_{\mathit{init}}}\right)\right)
+ ((\alpha)\mult d_g)\right] & \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ i}\ldots\\[15pt]
\left[\frac{y}{1-y\mult\left(r\bmod\frac{1}{y}\right)}\right]
\left[\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\mult\left(\frac{F_{\mathit{current}}}{F_{\mathit{init}}}\right)\right)
+ \left(\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\mult d_g\right)\right] & \text{if } n \in G, n \text{ is diffe}\ldots\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: I have changed `\mod` to `\bmod` as suggested by @egreg.

Comment: ! Looks quite nice! Did you install use any new package. I have tried compiling your code but I guess I need to install a package

Comment: Most likely, all `\mod` commands should be `\bmod`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks egreg. I will update the code.

Comment: @Abdulhameed: All the packages used will be available in your TeX distribution.

Comment: Please is there another approach without using the mathtools package?

Comment: @Abdulhameed: My answer did not use `mathtools` package. Please check the answer carefully.